# Where to begin Nietzsche?

Tags: reference-request, nietzsche

I am a mathematics student, but always interested in philosophical arguments especially on Love and God. I am also currently studying an extra course on philosophy of rationality which discusses science and religion well. Including Dawkins' God delusional.

Nietzsche has often attracted me. His thoughts that I have seen in his quotations attracts me. Can somebody tell me from which text I should start Nietzsche's work and then which one next in order. I do not want to stumble upon a harder text and then leave it halfway feeling boredom. Thanks in advance!